# OAuth Refresh token returns invalid_grant

Tags: .net, oauth

Like many people I used the [Taiser Joudah](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) article to create my refresh token provider (as well as his other article for creating the access token).  The odd thing for me is that it works fine on my local server but fails when I move it to another server.  Both the Auth and Resource server are the same server (same app actually).  Not sure what difference there could be on a different server. I've traced the SQL and it's performing the get and delete of the token so I know it's executing the code but the refresh returns invalid_grant every time and the user is logged out.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only place I see in the article where `invalid_grant` is returned:

```
using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
{
    IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Are you a username / password pair that exists on your non-local server?

If your local and non-local server do not share the same DB:

- You might be using an invalid refresh token, or it is expired or revoked
- The client credentials used might not match the client the refresh token was issued to

It could also be the redirect URI is different from your local server vs. non-local server.

```
invalid_grant
   The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization
   code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
   invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
   URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
   another client.
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2

Comment: I have the same invalid_grant code you show but that's in the GrantOwnerResourceCredentials method used for initial login.  As for the invalid_grant reasons from the spec I don't see where any of those would apply.  The refresh token parameters like expiration and or redirect URI (which is not being specified since this isn't a third party authentication provider implementation) don't change and it definitely wasn't issued to another client nor had it previously been revoked.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow so your local and non-local server share the same DB(s)? Also, any chance for a time skew?

Comment: No, the local and dev instances use their own DB (on different DB servers).  What time skew could there be when the access token and refresh token are generated on the same server within the same app?

Comment: @HisDivineShadow did you manage to resolve this. I am hitting the same brick wall. JWT works (and oddly if I request a new one within its lifetime with the refresh token, i can generate a new JWT), but when the JWT expires and I send the grant type as refresh_token over (again only when published) i receive the 'invalid_grant' error.

Now,  again as you say, the call is hitting the RefreshTokenProvider 'ReceiveAsync' but its then completely missing the 'CreateAsync' which is then called when locally??

Comment: @MatthewFlynn No, I never found out what was causing it because I changed my app to use a different authentication provider so it became moot point.  If you ever figure it out please post the answer here as I would still like to know what caused the problem.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow my issue was down to an odd issue where IIS was recycling the AppPool and so the Hash function was changing and therefore the login was failing. To fix this I just had to generate and set a MachineKey in the web.config. Does that sound familiar with your issue?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn I don't think that was my problem, no app pool recycling was going on  (at least that I'm aware of).  Glad you found your fix.